# Using filter and map in a pipe to reduce the set

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Just started working on RxJS and trying to wrap my head around `filter`. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter

From the looks of it, there's not much to figure out, I know? :S

This is what I have -

```
declare interface App {
  id: string;
  bId: string;
  account: string;
  title: string;
  platform: string;
  isLive: boolean;
}
```

```
public allApps: Observable<App[]>;

this.allApps = this.httpClient.get(`${UtilitiesService.APIRoot}/globals/apps`).pipe(
      map( response => response as App[] )
    );
```

This `get/pipe/map` gets me the object and casts it properly into `App[]` array. No issues so far!

Now I would like to `filter` out `bid !== null` and have only valid values in `this.allApps`. So I 'tried' to pass the output of `map` to `filter` like this -

```
this.allApps = this.httpClient.get(`${UtilitiesService.APIRoot}/globals/apps`).pipe(
      map( response => response as App[] ),
      filter( app => app.bid === null)
    );
```

As far as my readings/youtube videos go, the output of `map` (which is `App[]`) would get passed down to `filter` method. Then the `rxjs/filter` would 'automagically' loops thru each item? and weeds out null values.

But `filter` is somehow receiving `App[]`, forcing me to use the regular filter method on a regular array. (not trying to be fancy or anything like that, just trying to understand `rxjs/filter` :D)

Does anyone know how can I make `rxjs/filter` work please? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!! :pray:

Comment: Any reason your call doesn't look like `this.httpClient.get<App>()` which would type the result as `App` for you so you don't have to `map()`?

Comment: The `get` call will return multiple `App` objects. I have modified the `get` call to `get<Apps[]>`. Thanks for the tip, still trying to figure out these things with Angular :) I actually have another object - `Applications`, which has  `Apps[]` as it's member (looking to refactor it to make it simpler soon). This is why I am using `map` to just get the `apps` property - `map( response => response.apps )`

Comment: And you have `filter`  import at the top?

Comment: Yes! Imported `filter` (`import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do in the predicate function is dealing with the **response**, not with the series of responses.

`httpClient.get()` returns `Observable<App[]>` not `Observable<App>`. Which means `map` or `filter` functions get a single object `App[]`, so `filter` function gets only one array object as well as `map` function does.

Comment: My json object returns `Observable<App[]>`, that's why I am seeing `App[]` in the `filter`. Just want to confirm I understood this correct, right?

Comment: @PhaniAnne Yes it is.

Comment: Awesome. Now it makes sense. Thank you :) I just to need to stick to the boring `filter` on boring `array` I guess :D `map( response => response.apps.filter( app => app.bundleId !== null)`

Comment: @PhaniAnne When you use RxJS things other than methods in `HttpClient`, you could use `filter` or other RxJS functions usefully :)

Comment: Haha yes! I was just kidding :D

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you’re filtering out the “non null” values there.

I believe you are filtering the array (filtering App[] rather than each app) returned from the map method. Observables are a “stream”, so you’re interacting with the Observable from the map operator.

Try altering the second filter to a map, as such:

```
map(apps => apps.filter(app => app.bid != null))
```

to return the filtered apps.